# Collecting and data recording about successors of abstract model

Tags: python, django

My **app_templ** models definition:

**models.py**

```
class TableName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#
class TableAbstract(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
            abstract = True
```

It can be used by other apps:

**app1 / models.py**

```
from app_templ.models import TableAbstract
class Table1(TableAbstract):
    ...
```

**app2 / models.py**

```
from app_templ.models import TableAbstract
class Table2(TableAbstract):
    ...
```

and so on...

It is necessary for me that in TableName, names of models (tables) of successors registered.

How to make it by means of coding only in the **app_templ** app?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, what you are describing sounds fine. You are defining an abstract model and then using it to create several models. You do need to import it, and to specify that you want to create these tables (using your above examples). You should think carefully about *why* you are using the same model multiple times in different apps (should this actually be one app?), but in theory it is fine.

I don't quite understand your first definition, you should probably define your model something like this:

```
class TableBaseClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
            abstract = True
```

`abstract = True` will mean that the model is not created in your database ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)) so for clarity, you could store this file in a location distinct from your regular model classes that create tables.

This code:

```
from app_templ.models import TableAbstract
class Table1(TableAbstract):
    ...
```

should be in `models.py` in your app

Comment: app_templ - my app. As the model will be called in the applications that will use app_templ - I do not know yet.

the names of tables in the database (using PostgreSQL) I need to fine tune tables (connecting them to trigger functions in PostgreSQL)

Comment: I did not describe the problem completely. But the answer to my question, das I understand - where in my application (app_templ) to write this code.

Comment: "class TableAbstract" - provides a table with a special algorithm for creating a primary key. I need to connect all of the heirs to the trigger function. To do this, fill in the table "TableName"

Comment: It is necessary that in DB in table **app_templ_tablename** been collected 
    **id | name**:
    1 | app1_table1; 
    2 | app2_table2; 
    ...                      
Code should write in **app_templ/models.py**